# How to use UNION with two statements having ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, union

I am trying to get folders and files name from different tables, with result of EACH statement of query, sort by descending order of their `update_date` and than join it using `UNION`.

If I run these two queries separately, It does work and result will be retrieved from database according to descending order of date. But when I use `UNION` with them, It doesn't give me correct answer.

What could be the correct way to get it ?

```
(
    SELECT create_date, folder_name AS actual_name, folder_id, folder_displayed_name AS displayed_name, update_date, delete_flag, NULL AS img_url, NULL AS protect_flag, NULL AS file_type, list_order
    FROM aaaaa_estate.docs_folder
    WHERE delete_flag =0
    AND inside_of_folder =  ''
    ORDER BY update_date DESC

    )
    UNION (

    SELECT create_date, file_name AS actual_name, id, displayed_name, update_date, delete_flag, img_url, protect_flag, file_type, list_order
    FROM aaaaa_estate.docs_contract
    WHERE delete_flag =0
    AND inside_of =  ''
    ORDER BY update_date DESC
)
```

If I use Order By clause at the very end. It sort all data on the base of their `update_date` `ORDER BY DESC` which I never want.

I want to show docs list to user like Google shows in Google Drive, Always Folder first and files second .  Each of them Sorted by `update_date DESC`

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following where `ORDER BY` clause depends on two columns :

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT 1 qry_nr, create_date, folder_name AS actual_name, folder_id, folder_displayed_name AS displayed_name, update_date, delete_flag, NULL AS img_url, NULL AS protect_flag, NULL AS file_type, list_order
    FROM aaaaa_estate.docs_folder
    WHERE delete_flag =0
    AND inside_of_folder =  ''


    UNION 

    SELECT 2 qry_nr, create_date, file_name AS actual_name, id, displayed_name, update_date, delete_flag, img_url, protect_flag, file_type, list_order
    FROM aaaaa_estate.docs_contract
    WHERE delete_flag =0
    AND inside_of =  ''
 -- ORDER BY update_date DESC
) q
ORDER BY q.actual_name, q.qry_nr;
```

Comment: @Cheeko ok, I've edited, with respect to the picture it seems that the inner `ORDER BY` clause should be removed.

Comment: What is qry_nr ?

Comment: Please check result of your query at : https://i.snag.gy/oPq0mR.jpg .
It's still NOT working

Comment: @Cheeko I suppose you want this `ORDER BY q.actual_name, q.qry_nr`

Answer (score 0):

use order by out of the subquery

```
select t.* from 
(
    SELECT 1 as type, create_date, folder_name AS actual_name, folder_id, folder_displayed_name AS displayed_name, update_date, delete_flag, NULL AS img_url, NULL AS protect_flag, NULL AS file_type, list_order
    FROM aaaaa_estate.docs_folder
    WHERE delete_flag =0
    AND inside_of_folder =  ''   

    UNION     
    SELECT 2 ,create_date, file_name AS actual_name, id, displayed_name, update_date, delete_flag, img_url, protect_flag, file_type, list_order
    FROM aaaaa_estate.docs_contract
    WHERE delete_flag =0
    AND inside_of =  ''

) t order by type asc, update_date desc
```

As you mentioned that you  Always Folder first and files second so divide it two types to maintain proper ordering

Comment: I love you :) 
You saved my life :D

Comment: @Cheeko thanks happy to help, please accept it as a answer if it helps